# How to get sub-string in SAS by removing last two characters of string

Tags: function, sas

I have to get the sub-string from a given string in such a way that last two character will be wipe out from final output.

My data:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNTRx.png)

My Code:

```
data test;
set myclass.department;
last_name=scan(name,2,',');
run;
```

Please suggest on this.

Thanks!!

Comment: Is this homework? Try using the `length` and `substr` functions...

Comment: I would suggest that someone read the data in correctly, those last two letters look like states and I would suggest you fix the import step instead of fixing it after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Use Length() to calculate the length of the string before you subset it and use the SUBSTR() function with LENGTH()-2 which is the length you want.

Since I'm not typing out your data from a picture, I'm using the SASHELP.CLASS data set which you should have by default:

```
data class;
set sashelp.class;

new_name = substr(name, 1, length(name)-2);
run;

proc print;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

you were close and @Reeza suggestion about fixing the data at reading data is more appropriate and also by using her length statement. All you missed was substr function

```
data test;
set myclass.department;
lastname= substr(scan(name,2),1, length(scan(name,2,' '))-2);
run;
```

if your data is in same format always you can use prxchange like shown below.

```
  data TEST;
  set myclass.department ;
  length  lastname $25;
   lastname= prxchange('s/(.+\s+)(.+)(.{2})/$2/', -1, trim(name));
  RUN;
```

Answer (score 0):

`scan` is a good first step for extracting what is supposed to be the desired last name.  The second step is to remove the last two letters of the last name.

For the case of *toy* data, where you are learning first concepts, you can assume certain cleanliness (way 1.a).  You should also be aware of tacit things going on in the program data vector (pdv).  Learning subtle SAS-only features of certain functions is also beneficial (way 2)

```
data want;
  set have;
```

- extract `lastname` with `scan()`
  The storage space (I.e. the length attribute) of this variable will be set automatically to be the same as variable *name*.

  ```
  lastname = scan (name, 2, ',');
  ```
- blank out the last two characters of lastname using `substr` extraction

  - presume lastname value is always longer than 2 characters

    ```
    * way 1.a;

    lastname = substr(lastname, 1, length(lastname)-2);
    ```
  - handle the case of 'short' values that will cause `way 1.a` to LOG

    `NOTE: Invalid third argument to function SUBSTR at line ...`

    ```
    * way 1.b - presume 'lastname' content takes precedence over `state;

    if length(lastname) > 2 
      then lastname = substr(lastname, 1, length(lastname)-2);

    * way 1.c - presume 'state' content takes precedence over `lastname`

    if length(lastname) > 2 
      then lastname = substr(lastname, 1, length(lastname)-2);
      else lastname = ' ';
    ```
- wipe out last two characters, literally!

  ```
  * way 2 - substr() on the left hand side;

  substr(lastname, max(length(lastname)-1,1)) = ' ';
  ```

```
 run;
```